# StreamWriter writing to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, .net, stream, memorystream

I was under the impression that when you called `Flush()` in a StreamWriter object it writes to the underlying stream, but apparently this isn't the case with my code.

Instead of writing to my file it will just write nothing. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
    public FileResult DownloadEntries(int id)
    {
        Competition competition = dataService.GetCompetition(id);
        IQueryable<CompetitionEntry> entries = dataService.GetAllCompetitionEntries().Where(e => e.CompetitionId == competition.CompetitionId);

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter csvWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);

        csvWriter.WriteLine("First name,Second name,E-mail address,Preferred contact number,UserId\r\n");

        foreach (CompetitionEntry entry in entries)
        {
            csvWriter.WriteLine(String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}",
                entry.User.FirstName,
                entry.User.LastName,
                entry.User.Email,
                entry.User.PreferredContactNumber,
                entry.User.Id));
        }

        csvWriter.Flush();

        return File(stream, "text/plain", "CompetitionEntries.csv");
    }
```

Comment: Consider putting your MemoryStream and StreamWriter in using statements for proper garbage collection.

Comment: @neontapir I am not yet round to code cleanup but will after. Cheers

Comment: @neontapir, wrong comment for this particular case: this will only make problem more severe/obvious...

Comment: The using statement isn't necessary. Once the flush method is called the streamWriter is collected. On the return statement the garbage collector cleans up everything else.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I believe you need to set `Stream.Position = 0`. When you write, it advances the position to the end of the stream. When you pass it to `File()` it starts from the position it is at - the end.

I think the following will work (did not try to compile this):

```
stream.Position = 0;
return File(stream, "text/plain", "CompetitionEntries.csv");
```

And this way you are not creating any new objects or copying the underlying array.

Comment: Please note that you *must not* dispose writer and stream in controller's code. When copy-pasted you may need to add comment to your code about that.

Answer (score 10):

Your MemoryStream is positioned at the end. Better code would be to create new R/o memory stream on the same buffer using [MemoryStream(Byte[], Int32, Int32, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezk6t72e) constructor.

Simplest r/w on trimmed buffer:

```
 return File(new MemoryStream(stream.ToArray());
```

R/o without copying the internal buffer:

```
 return File(new MemoryStream(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Length, false);
```

Note: be careful not to dispose the stream you are returning via File(Stream). Otherwise you'll get "ObjectDisposedException" of some sort. I.e. if you simply set position of the original stream to 0 and wrap StreamWriter into using you'll get into returning disposed stream.

Comment: Interesting. As I show below, I was able to get something similar to work with the using statement.

Comment: @neontapir, you are not passing **original** stream, but instead `new MemoryStream(stream.ToArray())` which creates new non-disposed stream. ToArray/GetBuffer are OK to be called on disposed MemoryStream, but most other methods Read/Write are not.

Comment: Of course you're right, @AlexeiLevenkov, I had forgotten I'd done that refactoring.

Comment: Isn't it more efficient to set Stream.Position = 0 and use that stream instead of creating a duplicate MemoryStream object?

Comment: @DavidThielen, while it is more efficient to change position I prefer creation of new MemoryStream since it makes code more explicit and lets use normal `using` pattern to write data. Note that MemoryStream on existing buffer is very small object, so I think it is good price for correctly looking code. And if performance is so critical for particular piece of code I would not use MemoryStream due to its memory re-allocation strategy.

Answer (score 3):

In playing with this, I got the following prototype to work:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace StackOverflowSandbox
{
[TestFixture]
public class FileStreamResultTest
{
    public FileStreamResult DownloadEntries(int id)
    {
        // fake data
        var entries = new[] {new CompetitionEntry { User = new Competitor { FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Smith", Email = "jsmith@example.com", Id=id.ToString(), PreferredContactNumber = "555-1212"}}};

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var csvWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                csvWriter.WriteLine("First name,Second name,E-mail address,Preferred contact number,UserId\r\n");

                foreach (CompetitionEntry entry in entries)
                {
                    csvWriter.WriteLine(String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}",
                                                      entry.User.FirstName,
                                                      entry.User.LastName,
                                                      entry.User.Email,
                                                      entry.User.PreferredContactNumber,
                                                      entry.User.Id));
                }

                csvWriter.Flush();
            }

            return new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(stream.ToArray()), "text/plain");
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void CanRenderTest()
    {
        var fileStreamResult = DownloadEntries(1);
        string results;
        using (var stream = new StreamReader(fileStreamResult.FileStream))
        {
            results = stream.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Assert.IsNotEmpty(results);
    }
}

public class CompetitionEntry
{
    public Competitor User { get; set; }
}

public class Competitor
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public string Email;
    public string PreferredContactNumber;
    public string Id;
}
}
```